# Center nav item with Bootstrap 4 Flexbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, navigation, uinavigationbar, nav

I'm building a utility nav with Bootstrap 4 using flexbox classes.
I'm not able to center the middle item "Store: 297" with the full width of the nav bar, rather it's centering between the surrounding items.

Is there a way to make the centering relative to the nav bar rather than the items within the nav bar?

Thanks!

```html
<div class="utility navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="bd-highlight">
    <a class="customer-view-unlock" href="./index.html">
        <img src="assets/unlocked.svg" alt="customer-view-toggle"/>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="store-select mx-auto dropdown justify-content-center">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="store-select" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >Store: 297</a>
    <div class="mx-auto dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="store-select">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">298</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">299</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">300</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">301</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="notifications dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <h5>3</h5>
    </a>
    <div class="mx-auto dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="notifications">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Message 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Message 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Message 3</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Message 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- User -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link pr-5" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="media align-items-center">
          <span class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle">
            <img alt="Image placeholder" src="https://raw.githack.com/creativetimofficial/argon-dashboard/master/assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg"/>
          </span>
          <div class="media-body ml-2 d-none d-lg-block dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="mb-0 text-sm  font-weight-bold">Jessica Jones</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-arrow dropdown-menu-right">
        <div class=" dropdown-header noti-title">
          <h6 class="text-overflow m-0">Welcome!</h6>
        </div>
        <a href="../examples/profile.html" class="dropdown-item">
          <i class="ni ni-single-02"></i>
          <span>My profile</span>
        </a>
        <a href="../examples/profile.html" class="dropdown-item">
          <i class="ni ni-settings-gear-65"></i>
          <span>Settings</span>
        </a>
        <a href="../examples/profile.html" class="dropdown-item">
          <i class="ni ni-calendar-grid-58"></i>
          <span>Activity</span>
        </a>
        <a href="../examples/profile.html" class="dropdown-item">
          <i class="ni ni-support-16"></i>
          <span>Support</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a href="#!" class="dropdown-item">
          <i class="ni ni-user-run"></i>
          <span>Logout</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use following `css` for item "`Store: 297`" :

```
.store-select{
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

And also add class "`ml-auto`" for notifications dropdown